# Applying Google Visualization CategoryFilter to Spreadsheet Column Containing a List of Comma Separated Values

Tags: csv, charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I have created a Table Chart according to [Google's Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference) and published the web app [here](https://script.google.com/a/dpsnc.net/macros/s/AKfycbzu4V4IkndD7huKaxDpM63L4gL2YHR2nOBvlrRnjMrd/dev). The data source is [a Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DOTezFuzpH8wzeh25Cgv9e9q577zd_HN1TiIxVQzbUQ/edit#gid=0) with Google Form responses. A couple columns contain a list of comma separated values, which are responses of the form's Checklist items. I have applied a "CategoryFilter" to these columns. However, instead of individualizing each comma separated value it treats it as one value.

[Image of CSV Values not Separated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikja8.png)

I would like for the filter to separate the values based on the comma and then stack them in a dropdown list. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried creating the values according to the API for the values for the "Grade Level(s)" filter, but when I choose one of the values in the filter it finds no result (I assume because the CategoryFilter does not do partial matches).

```
 var gradeLevels = ['K-2','3-5'];

   var GradeLevelCategoryFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'GradeLevelCategoryFilter',
      'options': {
       'filterColumnIndex': '11',
       'matchType': 'any',
       'allowTyping': true,
       'values' : gradeLevels,
       'ui': {
       'labelStacking': 'horizontal',
       'label': '',
       'caption' : 'Filter by Grade Level(s)',
       'selectedValuesLayout': 'aside',
       'sortValues' : false,
       }
      }
    });
```

Comment: you would need to manually fill the `values` property, as you have done, from all the rows in the table -- you would also need to _unbind_ and handle the filter manually on the `'statechange'` event

Comment: Thank you for the response, WhiteHat. I really appreciate it! I am at a loss of how to do the manual filter, however. Would I still use a CategoryFilter? I have created a JSFiddle hoping you can provide me a little more direction. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=iO0RrnVN50)

Comment: [JSFiddle using Category Filter](https://jsfiddle.net/jerryawilliamson/L1y0Lh99/5/#&togetherjs=iO0RrnVN50)

Comment: I adapted code from [Cyberliving.com](http://cyberliving.blogspot.com) to that does not bind the filter to the table, but manually filter the data via query. However, I do not know how to "combine" the filters. For instance, if I choose K-2 in the filter, that filter is overridden when I click on 3-5. I need to stack them. And then if I create a filter for subject areas, I need to stack them with the grade levels. Here is a JS Fiddle using a manual checkbox filter 
 (https://jsfiddle.net/jerryawilliamson/9stvza73/#&togetherjs=iO0RrnVN50)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the spreadsheet loads,
use data table method `getDistinctValues(index)` on the column
this will return a distinct list of the column values
then split each value on comma and build a unique list of the choices
use the choices for the `values` option on the filter

then on the filter's `'statechange'` event,
use data table method `getFilteredRows()` to find the row indexes
which contain the filter's selected choice(s)
use the row indexes to set a view on the chart

see following working snippet, a table chart is used...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['controls', 'corechart', 'table']
}).then(function () {
  var sheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DOTezFuzpH8wzeh25Cgv9e9q577zd_HN1TiIxVQzbUQ/edit#gid=0';

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'chart-table',
    options: {
      allowHtml: true
    }
  });

  var filter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'filter-grade',
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 12,
      matchType: 'any',
      allowTyping: true,
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'horizontal',
        label: '',
        caption: 'Filter by Grade Level(s)',
        selectedValuesLayout: 'aside',
        sortValues: false
      }
    }
  });

  new google.visualization.Query(sheet).send(function (response) {
    var data = response.getDataTable();
    var gradeAnswers = data.getDistinctValues(12);
    var gradeChoices = [];
    gradeAnswers.forEach(function (answer) {
      if (answer !== null) {
        var choices = answer.split(',');
        choices.forEach(function (choice) {
          choice = choice.trim();
          if (gradeChoices.indexOf(choice) === -1) {
            gradeChoices.push(choice);
          }
        });
      }
    });
    gradeChoices.sort();

    google.visualization.events.addListener(filter, 'statechange', function () {
      var state = filter.getState().selectedValues;
      table.setView(null);
      if (state.length > 0) {
        table.setView({
          rows: data.getFilteredRows([{
            column: 12,
            test: function (value) {
              var found = false;
              if (value !== null) {
                state.forEach(function (selected) {
                  if (value.indexOf(selected) > -1) {
                    found = true;
                  }
                });
              }
              return found;
            }
          }])
        });
      }
      table.draw();
    });

    filter.setDataTable(data);
    filter.setOption('values', gradeChoices);
    filter.draw();
    table.setDataTable(data);
    table.draw();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="filter-grade"></div>
<div id="chart-table"></div>
```

**EDIT**

you can set the view on the initial definition...

```
var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  chartType: 'Table',
  containerId: 'chart-table',
  options: {
    allowHtml: true
  },
  view: {
    columns: [0]
  }
});
```

or use the `setView` method...

```
table.setView({
  columns: [0]
});
```

**EDIT 2**

```
  var view = {
    columns: [0]
  };
  if (state.length > 0) {
    view.rows = data.getFilteredRows([{
      column: 12,
      test: function (value) {
        var found = false;
        if (value !== null) {
          state.forEach(function (selected) {
            if (value.indexOf(selected) > -1) {
              found = true;
            }
          });
        }
        return found;
      }
    }]);
  }
  table.setView(view);
```

**EDIT 3**

you can combine multiple filters into an array,
before passing to `getFilteredRows`

```
var view = {
  columns: [0]
};
var viewFilters = [];
if (stateGrade.length > 0) {
  viewFilters.push({
    column: 12,
    test: function (value) {
      var found = false;
      if (value !== null) {
        stateGrade.forEach(function (selected) {
          if (value.indexOf(selected) > -1) {
            found = true;
          }
        });
      }
      return found;
    }
  });
}
if (stateSubject.length > 0) {
  viewFilters.push({
    column: subjectIndex,
    test: function (value) {
      var found = false;
      if (value !== null) {
        stateSubject.forEach(function (selected) {
          if (value.indexOf(selected) > -1) {
            found = true;
          }
        });
      }
      return found;
    }
  });
}
view.rows = data.getFilteredRows(viewFilters);
table.setView(view);
```

Comment: This helps tremendously, @WhiteHat. The filter works great. Where would I set options for the table in this configuration, like: 
         'view': {columns: [0]}  
        });?

Comment: this works for the initial draw, but once the filter is used, all columns appear. [demo](https://script.google.com/a/dpsnc.net/macros/s/AKfycbwKGhm1GfbuHpDbgrLlRbyb_5cM8-niEa4lvPgsmtM/dev)

Comment: need to add the `columns` definition to the `setView` method in the `'statechange'` event, see __EDIT 2__...

Comment: @WhiteHat- you are a kind genius. Thank you so much! Now I am going to try to do add a second filter, that does the same thing, with the subject areas.

Comment: now that I have added a second filter [see here](https://script.google.com/a/dpsnc.net/macros/s/AKfycbwKGhm1GfbuHpDbgrLlRbyb_5cM8-niEa4lvPgsmtM/dev}, is there a way to bind the results without the dashboard. I would like the filters to work together, but now they cancel the other's previous results. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jerryawilliamson/L1y0Lh99/8/#&togetherjs=8zl4PVIqkV)

Comment: Do I add edit 3 to both event listeners? - -
    google.visualization.events.addListener(gradeFilter, 'statechange', function () {       google.visualization.events.addListener(subjectFilter, 'statechange', function () { @WhiteHat

Comment: @WhiteHat- I deeply appreciate the help. I am still struggling. When I combine the filters in a function called in the listeners, I get no response. Do you seen anything I coded incorrectly? [JS Fiddle with combinedFilters function](https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=yupueiADCF) Any insights would, again, be greatly appreciated!