# Filter Google Visualization Table Chart by Pointing Multiple Statechange Events to One Function

Tags: javascript, charts, google-apps-script, google-visualization

With [tremendous help from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081652/applying-google-visualization-categoryfilter-to-spreadsheet-column-containing-a) @WHiteHat, I have a Google Visualization Table Chart 
[here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzB_S2CZ9PrQAugt_0uvRHIGHV2dzgwtp9aXWNphi1mfMBACMxb/exec) that works well. It has two filters, but they work independently. They cancel the other's previous results. You can see the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jerryawilliamson/kngcuvdu/). Each filter has a listener and built in function.

```
//listen for changes in grade level filter
google.visualization.events.addListener(gradeFilter, 'statechange', function () {
var state = gradeFilter.getState().selectedValues;
var view = {columns: [0]};
if (state.length > 0) {
view.rows = data.getFilteredRows([{
  column: 12,
  test: function (value) {
    var found = false;
    if (value !== null) {
      state.forEach(function (selected) {
        if (value.indexOf(selected) > -1) {
          found = true;}});}
    return found;
  }}]);}
 table.setView(view);
 table.draw();});

//listen for changes in grade level filter
google.visualization.events.addListener(subjectFilter, 'statechange', function () {
var state = subjectFilter.getState().selectedValues;
var view = {columns: [0]};
if (state.length > 0) {
view.rows = data.getFilteredRows([{
  column: 10,
  test: function (value) {
    var found = false;
    if (value !== null) {
      state.forEach(function (selected) {
        if (value.indexOf(selected) > -1) {
          found = true;}});}
    return found;
  }}]);}
 table.setView(view);
 table.draw();});
```

I would like the filters to work in combination. Again, @WhiteHat provided a ton of help with combining the filters into an array, before passing to .getFilteredRows.

Now I need to point both filters to a separate function. That is where I am stuck. I added a listener for each filter that points to a function named "combineFilters."

However, the function does not run. I am not sure of the reason or how to fix it.

I cannot seem to find examples of calling an external function in an event listener.

Below is the part of the code that deals with the listeners and combineFilter function. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jerryawilliamson/2fh0ddrn/) is the code in its entirety. Any solutions on how to combine the results of multiple filters?

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(gradeFilter, 'statechange', combineFilters);
google.visualization.events.addListener(subjectFilter, 'statechange', combineFilters);
});

function combineFilters(){

var stateGrade = gradeFilter.getState().selectedValues;
var stateSubject = subjectFilter.getState().selectedValues;
var view = {
columns: [0]
};
var viewFilters = [];
if (stateGrade.length > 0) {
viewFilters.push({
column: 12,
test: function (value) {
  var found = false;
  if (value !== null) {
    stateGrade.forEach(function (selected) {
      if (value.indexOf(selected) > -1) {
        found = true;
      }
    });
  }
  return found;
  }
  });
  }
  if (stateSubject.length > 0) {
  viewFilters.push({
column: 10,
test: function (value) {
  var found = false;
  if (value !== null) {
    stateSubject.forEach(function (selected) {
      if (value.indexOf(selected) > -1) {
        found = true;
      }
    });
  }
  return found;
}
});
}
view.rows = data.getFilteredRows(viewFilters);
table.setView(view);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main problem was due to scoping...

you were declaring the data, table, filters in one function,
and trying to use them in another...

the variable declarations need to be outside of the function,
to use the same variables in another function...

just move the `var` statements out,
and remove the `var` part out of the function,
see below...

another issue was when the filter choices are cleared,
only set `view.rows` if a filter exists...

see following working snippet...

```js
// MOVE declarations here
var data;
var table;
var gradeFilter;
var subjectFilter;

google.charts.load('current', {packages:['controls', 'corechart', 'table']}).then(function () {
  var sheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DOTezFuzpH8wzeh25Cgv9e9q577zd_HN1TiIxVQzbUQ/edit#gid=0';

  // REMOVE var here    
  table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'chart-table',
    options: {allowHtml: true}});

  gradeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'filter-grade',
    options: {filterColumnIndex: 12,matchType: 'any',allowTyping: true,
      ui: {labelStacking: 'horizontal',label: '',caption: 'Filter by Grade Level(s)',selectedValuesLayout: 'below',sortValues: false }}});

  subjectFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'filter-subject',
    options: {filterColumnIndex: 10,matchType: 'any',allowTyping: true,
      ui: {labelStacking: 'horizontal',label: '',caption: 'Filter by Subject Area(s)',selectedValuesLayout: 'below',sortValues: false }}});

  //query sheet for grade levels
  new google.visualization.Query(sheet).send(function (response) {
    data = response.getDataTable();
    var gradeAnswers = data.getDistinctValues(12);
    var gradeChoices = [];
    gradeAnswers.forEach(function (answer) {
      if (answer !== null) {
        var choices = answer.split(',');
        choices.forEach(function (choice) {
          choice = choice.trim();
          if (gradeChoices.indexOf(choice) === -1) {
            gradeChoices.push(choice);}
        }); } });
    gradeChoices.sort();

    //query sheet for subject areas
    var subjectAnswers = data.getDistinctValues(10);
    var subjectChoices = [];
    subjectAnswers.forEach(function (subjectAnswer) {
      if (subjectAnswer !== null) {
        var subjectAreaChoices = subjectAnswer.split(',');
        subjectAreaChoices.forEach(function (subjectAreaChoice) {
          subjectAreaChoice = subjectAreaChoice.trim();
          if (subjectChoices.indexOf(subjectAreaChoice) === -1) {
            subjectChoices.push(subjectAreaChoice);}
        }); } });
    subjectChoices.sort();

    gradeFilter.setDataTable(data);
    gradeFilter.setOption('values', gradeChoices);
    gradeFilter.draw();

    subjectFilter.setDataTable(data);
    subjectFilter.setOption('values', subjectChoices);
    subjectFilter.draw();

    table.setView({columns: [0]});
    table.setDataTable(data);
    table.draw();

   });
   google.visualization.events.addListener(gradeFilter, 'statechange', combineFilters);
   google.visualization.events.addListener(subjectFilter, 'statechange', combineFilters);
});

function combineFilters(){
  var stateGrade = gradeFilter.getState().selectedValues;
  var stateSubject = subjectFilter.getState().selectedValues;
  var view = {
    columns: [0]
  };
  table.setView(view);
  var viewFilters = [];
  if (stateGrade.length > 0) {
    viewFilters.push({
      column: 12,
      test: function (value) {
        var found = false;
        if (value !== null) {
          stateGrade.forEach(function (selected) {
            if (value.indexOf(selected) > -1) {
              found = true;
            }
          });
        }
        return found;
      }
    });
  }
  if (stateSubject.length > 0) {
    viewFilters.push({
      column: 10,
      test: function (value) {
        var found = false;
        if (value !== null) {
          stateSubject.forEach(function (selected) {
            if (value.indexOf(selected) > -1) {
              found = true;
            }
          });
        }
        return found;
      }
    });
  }
  if (viewFilters.length > 0) {
    view.rows = data.getFilteredRows(viewFilters);
    table.setView(view);
  }
  table.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="filter-grade"></div>
<div id="filter-subject"></div>
<div id="chart-table"></div>
```

**EDIT -- added string filter**

```js
var data;
var table;
var gradeFilter;
var subjectFilter;
var stringFilter;

google.charts.load('current', {packages:['controls', 'corechart', 'table']}).then(function () {
  var sheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DOTezFuzpH8wzeh25Cgv9e9q577zd_HN1TiIxVQzbUQ/edit#gid=0';

  table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'chart-table',
    options: {allowHtml: true}});

  gradeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'filter-grade',
    options: {filterColumnIndex: 12,matchType: 'any',allowTyping: true,
      ui: {labelStacking: 'horizontal',label: '',caption: 'Filter by Grade Level(s)',selectedValuesLayout: 'below',sortValues: false }}});

  subjectFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'filter-subject',
    options: {filterColumnIndex: 10,matchType: 'any',allowTyping: true,
      ui: {labelStacking: 'horizontal',label: '',caption: 'Filter by Subject Area(s)',selectedValuesLayout: 'below',sortValues: false }}});

  stringFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'StringFilter',
    containerId: 'filter-title',
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 1,
      ui: {
        caption: 'Filter by Title'
      }
    }
  });

  //query sheet for grade levels
  new google.visualization.Query(sheet).send(function (response) {
    data = response.getDataTable();
    var gradeAnswers = data.getDistinctValues(12);
    var gradeChoices = [];
    gradeAnswers.forEach(function (answer) {
      if (answer !== null) {
        var choices = answer.split(',');
        choices.forEach(function (choice) {
          choice = choice.trim();
          if (gradeChoices.indexOf(choice) === -1) {
            gradeChoices.push(choice);}
        }); } });
    gradeChoices.sort();

    //query sheet for subject areas
    var subjectAnswers = data.getDistinctValues(10);
    var subjectChoices = [];
    subjectAnswers.forEach(function (subjectAnswer) {
      if (subjectAnswer !== null) {
        var subjectAreaChoices = subjectAnswer.split(',');
        subjectAreaChoices.forEach(function (subjectAreaChoice) {
          subjectAreaChoice = subjectAreaChoice.trim();
          if (subjectChoices.indexOf(subjectAreaChoice) === -1) {
            subjectChoices.push(subjectAreaChoice);}
        }); } });
    subjectChoices.sort();

    stringFilter.setDataTable(data);
    stringFilter.draw();

    gradeFilter.setDataTable(data);
    gradeFilter.setOption('values', gradeChoices);
    gradeFilter.draw();

    subjectFilter.setDataTable(data);
    subjectFilter.setOption('values', subjectChoices);
    subjectFilter.draw();

    table.setView({columns: [0]});
    table.setDataTable(data);
    table.draw();

   });
   google.visualization.events.addListener(stringFilter, 'statechange', combineFilters);
   google.visualization.events.addListener(gradeFilter, 'statechange', combineFilters);
   google.visualization.events.addListener(subjectFilter, 'statechange', combineFilters);
});

function combineFilters(){
  var stateGrade = gradeFilter.getState().selectedValues;
  var stateSubject = subjectFilter.getState().selectedValues;
  var view = {
    columns: [0]
  };
  table.setView(view);
  var viewFilters = [];

  var stateString = stringFilter.getState().value;
  if (stateString !== '') {
    // partial match -- NOT case sensitive
    viewFilters.push({
      column: 1,
      test: function (value) {
        return (value.toLowerCase().indexOf(stateString.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      }
    });

/*
    // partial match -- case sensitive
    viewFilters.push({
      column: 1,
      test: function (value) {
        return (value.indexOf(stateString) > -1);
      }
    });

    // exact match -- case sensitive
    viewFilters.push({
      column: 1,
      value: stateString
    });

    // exact match -- NOT case sensitive
    viewFilters.push({
      column: 1,
      test: function (value) {
        return (value.toLowerCase() === stateString.toLowerCase());
      }
    });
*/
  }

  if (stateGrade.length > 0) {
    viewFilters.push({
      column: 12,
      test: function (value) {
        var found = false;
        if (value !== null) {
          stateGrade.forEach(function (selected) {
            if (value.indexOf(selected) > -1) {
              found = true;
            }
          });
        }
        return found;
      }
    });
  }
  if (stateSubject.length > 0) {
    viewFilters.push({
      column: 10,
      test: function (value) {
        var found = false;
        if (value !== null) {
          stateSubject.forEach(function (selected) {
            if (value.indexOf(selected) > -1) {
              found = true;
            }
          });
        }
        return found;
      }
    });
  }
  if (viewFilters.length > 0) {
    view.rows = data.getFilteredRows(viewFilters);
    table.setView(view);
  }
  table.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="filter-title"></div>
<div id="filter-grade"></div>
<div id="filter-subject"></div>
<div id="chart-table"></div>
```

Comment: another option would be to leave the declarations where they were, but move the entire `combineFilters` function into the same function as the declarations...

Comment: I cannot thank or compliment you enough. Your knowledge, skills, and generosity are lifesavers.

Comment: One more question- is there a way to include a stringFilter in the combineFilters() function? When I bind a stringFilter to the dashboard, separate from the function, it sort of works, but get some errors (e.g. "Invalid row index 6. Should be in the range [0-0]") because the table size, obviously, changes when a selection in one or more of the categoryFilters are used. [link](https://script.google.com/a/dpsnc.net/macros/s/AKfycby2HxpzPVSuf9QkytCzEW9L2mdE_Y8oLLmZp0Y4qBFDWn56KJ6n/exec). Is there a stringFilter equivalent to getting "selected" for the stringFilter? @WhiteHat

Comment: var stateString = stringFilter.getState().value;  var viewFilters = [];

  if (stateString.length > 0) {
    viewFilters.push({
      column: 12,
      test: function (value) {
        var found = false;
        if (value !== null) {
          stateString.forEach(function (selected) {
            if (value.indexOf(selected) > -1) {
              found = true;
            }
          });
        }
        return found;
      }
    });
  }

Comment: see __EDIT__ above -- added string filter and 4 different options depending on the type of match you need -- 3 are commented out...

Comment: Wow, @WhiteHat! That is simply perfect! Thank you for teaching this. I have a ton of cases to apply these examples to.